# Best way to save regression equations in R ?

Tags: r, regression

I have a large number of regression equations that I would like to save in R and I am not sure how to do it efficiently. For example,

```
y1 ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4  (country A) 
y1 ~ x1 + x2 +      x4  (country B) 
y1 ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4  (country C) 
y1 ~         + x3 + x4  (country D)
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to answers such as how many times x2 occurred ? 3.
what is the most common variable ? x4

Should I save everything in a list ? or is there a better method ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put them in a list:

```
myformulas <- 
list(a = y1 ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4,
     b = y1 ~ x1 + x2 +      x4,
     c = y1 ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4,
     d = y1 ~         + x3 + x4)
```

You can then perform operations on them like:

```
# what variables are in which formulae
> str(lapply(myformulas, function(x) attr(terms(x), 'term.labels')))
List of 4
 $ a: chr [1:4] "x1" "x2" "x3" "x4"
 $ b: chr [1:3] "x1" "x2" "x4"
 $ c: chr [1:4] "x1" "x2" "x3" "x4"
 $ d: chr [1:2] "x3" "x4"

# where is `x1` used?
> str(lapply(myformulas, function(x) 'x1' %in% attr(terms(x), 'term.labels')))
List of 4
 $ a: logi TRUE
 $ b: logi TRUE
 $ c: logi TRUE
 $ d: logi FALSE

# how many times is each variable used?
> table(unlist(lapply(myformulas, function(x) attr(terms(x), 'term.labels'))))
x1 x2 x3 x4 
 3  3  3  4
```

From that structure you could easily answer your questions about the use of different variables.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you prefer a model like this and glm?

```
y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + country
```

Let the regression tell you which factors drop out.